Discrepancy in Password Encryption between PHP and Node.js using str_rot13, gzdeflate, and base64_encode
I am migrating an application from PHP to Node.js and have encountered an issue with password encryption. In the original PHP system, passwords are encrypted using \str_rot13, \gzdeflate, and `base64_encode. I have tried to replicate this logic in Node.js, but the resulting encryption does not match what is generated in PHP. Here are the implementation details:
Original PHP Code
<?php
$b = $_GET["clave"];
echo $clavecodificada = base64_encode(gzdeflate(str_rot13($b)));
?>`

Problem
When I encrypt the password in PHP, I get the following result:
Original password: PAPITAS1
Encrypted password (PHP): c/ZzDnP3czMEAA==
However, when I use the Node.js code to encrypt the same password, I get:
Original password: PAPITAS1
Encrypted password (Node.js): eJxz9nMOc/dzMwQACkUCNw==
The encryption results do not match, causing the database query to find no matches.
Question
How can I adjust my Node.js code to ensure the password encryption matches the PHP encryption using str_rot13, gzdeflate, and base64_encode?
Any help would be appreciated.
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '???',
    user: '???',
    password: '???',
    database: '???',
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
});

db.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Database connection failed:', err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to database');
});

function str_rot13(str) {
    return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function (c) {
        return String.fromCharCode(
            c.charCodeAt(0) + (c.toLowerCase() < 'n' ? 13 : -13)
        );
    });
}

function encryptPassword(password) {
    console.log("Original password:", password);
    const rot13Password = str_rot13(password);
    console.log("After ROT13:", rot13Password);
    const deflatedPassword = zlib.deflateSync(Buffer.from(rot13Password, 'utf-8')).toString('base64');
    console.log("After deflate and base64 encoding:", deflatedPassword);
    return deflatedPassword;
}

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    console.log('Received username:', username);
    console.log('Received password:', password);

    if (!username || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Username and password are required' });
    }

    const upperUsername = username.toUpperCase();
    const encryptedPassword = encryptPassword(password);

    console.log('Encrypted password:', encryptedPassword);

    const query = 'SELECT idusuario, status FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND clave = ?';
    db.query(query, [upperUsername, encryptedPassword], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Database query failed:', error.stack);
            return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Database query failed' });
        }

        console.log('Query results:', results);

        if (results.length > 0) {
            const user = results[0];
            const updateQuery = 'UPDATE usuarios SET acceso = 1 WHERE idusuario = ?';
            db.query(updateQuery, [user.idusuario], (err, updateResults) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Failed to update user:', err.stack);
                    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to update user' });
                }

                return res.json({ success: true, userId: user.idusuario, status: user.status });
            });
        } else {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password' });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


take this opportunity to switch your password storage to something modern, preferably a hash, not encryption.  otherwise: I don't know of any reason to expect one gzdeflate library output to exactly match a different one or a different library version, though you should be able to inflate and check the plaintext for a match

note that the usual flow for hashed passwords is not to use them in the select where, but to just select the user's encrypted password and in code verify it matches, so it can include random salt.

PHP gzdeflate() is not zlib encoded so I think you need to use zlib.deflateRawSync() instead.

The fact that none of this is encryption aside, even if you were hashing/encrypting doing so client-side like this just turns the hash/ciphertext into the de-facto password. Use SSL and send the password to the server to be hashed and compared properly.

@Sammitch "none of this is encryption" ROT13 is a cipher. It's not modern, of course, but it is a cipher.

As noted, this is merely password obfuscation. An attacker with access to the "encrypted" password can recover the password just as easily as you can check it.

No one in the comments has come out and said it directly yet, but you need to stop storing passwords this way. It is not secure. You are compromising your customers' login credentials. You should have no higher priority than removing this from your system.
